# Why Typescript compiler ignores check, when its result set to a variable?

Tags: typescript

I like to put a long conditional statement into a variable like this:

```
const valid = a && a.someLongFieldName > 10;

if (valid) { 
  console.log(a.someLongFieldName); 
}
```

TypeScript compiler complaining about it: `Object is possibly 'undefined'`. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any workaround for situations like this? I know this can be fixed by using `a!.someLongFieldName`, but it's a bit tough.

Comment: You wrote "I know this can't be fixed". Did you meant "CAN be fixed" ?

Comment: Yes. My mistake